# How I can change folder for creating files in project?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, web-applications, log4j

I created java maven web-application in IntelliJ Idea. When I try to create file for log(log4j.log) throught .xml file it creates but in Tomcat/bin folder. I'd like to create that file in project folder.

I've solved that problem on this way: 
change this part of .xml file

```
<param name="file" value="log4j.log"/>
```

to this

```
<param name="file" value="C:/Users/Igor/IdeaProjects/JA_Project/log4j.log"/>
```

The main problem I have to share my project on gitHub and If anybody else downloaded this project He'd have a problem because path on his computer is different

logger.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>



 <appender name="console"
              class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="fileAppender"
              class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="C:/Users/Igor/IdeaProjects/JA_Lesson__6/log4j.log"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <param name="threshold" value="error"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>

        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="levelMin" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="levelMax" value="ERROR" />
        </filter>

    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**How I can change folder for creating files in project?**

Answer (score 0):

When I start server I can see such line:
Using CATALINA_BASE:  "C:\Users\Igor.IntelliJIdea2019.3\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_19_Task"

My solution was to set

`<param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/server.log"/>`

instead of

`<param name="file" value="C:/Users/Igor/IdeaProjects/JA_Lesson__6/log4j.log"/>`

Everyone has own path to CATALINA_BASE but structure inside is the same! 
It makes sense to use this "${catalina.base}/logs/"